# How to set message headers using KafkaTemplate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm building a Spring Boot 2.4.4 application to produce message to Kafka (Confluent Platform), using schema validation.
The schema is set up on the schema registry for the topic, and I've created the POJO (`LoanInitiate`) from the associated AVSC file using the Maven Avro plugin. When sending using the following, there are no issues:

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
...

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, LoanInitiate> kafkaTemplate;

@Value("${kafka.topic}")
private String topic;


public void regularSend(){
    LoanInitiate li = initializeLoanInitiate();
    kafkaTemplate.send(topic, li); //ok
}
```

However, if I attempt the following, I will get `Unsupported Avro type.`

```
@Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Message<LoanInitiate>> kafkaTemplate2;

public void sendMessage(){
     Message<LoanInitiate> message = MessageBuilder
                                    .withPayload(li)
                                    .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, "Correlation ID")
                                    .build();
     kafkaTemplate2.send(topic, message); //"Unsupported Avro type"

}
```

My producer configuration is as follows:

```
#Producer values
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
```

I understand that the `kafkaTemplate2` is trying to send a `Message<LoanInitiate>` and not a `LoanInitiate` but it's not clear to me what I am missing to provide for writing the message and header.

How should I approach sending my message along with header information?

Answer (score 2):

After working through several iterations, posting the question, and then taking a break I found a solution by using `ProducerRecord`

```
ProducerRecord<String, LoanInitiate> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, li);
            producerRecord
            .headers()
            .add(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, 
            "Correlation ID".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
```

Answer (score 2):

With the version in the question, it depends on whether Jackson is on the class path; if it is, the default `MessagingMessageConverter` gets a `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` which can map headers of any json-friendly type, otherwise you get a `SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper` which only maps headers with `byte[]` values.

So, if you add `getBytes()` to the value, it should work.

You can add a `MessagingMessageConverter` configured with a `SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper` to the template with its `mapAllStringsOut` set to true which will also map headers with `String` values.

On the inbound side, you can map back to a String by setting the `rawMappedHeaders` property appropriately.

You can also use your own custom header mapper.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#headers and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion

as well as the Javadocs for the mappers.

Comment: I added `getBytes()` to the header value but received the same error. I'm going to try the recommendations for configuration next.